# scrape data from json response scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am try to scrape a website but that website stores required data in json format. I used spider to get data from a url. I cannot understand the json response as I am a beginner in scrapy especially json format I want to extract dogId and the msgTimeOff. I tried randomly sometimes got key error or the data was not the required one. One block which contains the required data is as below

```
{"raceId":"1808334","position":"6","trap":"6","resultHandicap":"","name":"Turkey 
Blaze","dogSex":"D","dogDateOfBirth":"2017-05-01 05:00","dogSire":"SIDARIAN BLAZE","dogDam":"MISS PRECEDENT","msgTimeOff":"2021-01-05 
13:49","status":"6","reservename":"","dogId":"532771","reserveDogId":"","comment":"wide, crowded 
run-up and first","withdrawreason":"Wide,CrdRnUp&1","calcRTimeS":29.82,"dogColor":"bk","fract":"10\/1","trainer
":"A Jenkins","favFlag":"","rpDistDesc":"1 1\/4","splitTime":"4.68","winnersTimeS":"29.48","raceStatus":"P","rStatusCde":"P","finalROutcomeId":
"6","reserveYn":"","isNonRunner":"0","isReserved":"0","videoid":""}
```

it is contained in a list and there are many lists available. I want to extract all of it
the code I use to get json response is

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "timeline"
    def __init__(self,date='', *args,**kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.date = date
        self.start_urls = ['https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/results/blocks.sd?race_id=1808334&track_id=4&r_date='+ date +'&r_time=13%3A49&blocks=meetingHeader%2Cresults-meeting-pager%2Clist']
    def parse2(self, response):
        jsn_data = response.json()
        for datas in jsn_data['list']['forecasts']:
            print(datas)
if __name__ == '__main__'
   spider = 'timeline'
   date = '2021-01-05'
   settings = get_project_settings()
   settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
   process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
   process.crawl(spider, date = date)
   process.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get raceIds

every raceId has a items , every item has dogId
like this[image]

Comment: It would be better to include the solutoin as code snippet rather than an image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JSON you're getting with better visual

[image: Here is the JSON you're getting with better visual]

The json object has several key and values including **dogId (Line 14)** and **msgTimeOff (Line 11)**. You can take similar approach handling it like a python dictionary

So, in the **parse_2** method,

> ```
> def parse2(self, response):    
>     jsn_data = response.json()
>     for datas in jsn_data['list']['forecasts']:
>         print(datas)
>         dogId = datas.get('dogId') #Will return None if key not found
>         msgTimeOff = datas.get('msgTimeOff')
> ```